# Enter just persian text in text box using javascript?

Tags: jquery

I am create small demo for write persian text enter in text box.i am search some links and try this code but this is not enter persian text enter only english text so can you please help me how can do that.and also want to validation on national id.

this is my html text box :

```
<input type="text" id="txtn" onkeypress="text(this)">
```

this is my js code :

```
function text(name)
{
    var name = $(name).val();           
    just_persian(name);
}

 function just_persian(str) {
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
    if (!p.test(str)) {
        alert("not format");
    }
}
```

here i am enter any text always getting alert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
$("#txtn").on('change keyup paste keydown', function(e) {        
    if(just_persian(e.key) === false)
        e.preventDefault();
});


function just_persian(str) {
   var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
   if (!p.test(str)) {
       return false
   }
   return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtn">
```

I hope this work :)

Comment: Thanks for the helping but now i want to also add Passport number validation and National Id validation for iran so any idea about it this??

Comment: Additional to checking Persian characters?

Comment: that mean i can't  understand can you please let me know how can do that??Passport number is for indian and iranian for nationalid

Comment: You can achieve to that goal with masked input

Comment: For passport i am used this regx string "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}".

Comment: @coderwill This two regex is opposite to each other. WIth first regex you wanna enter Persian characters only and with second one you wanna have English characters allowed in your input!

Comment: can you please suggest the "012-345678-9" this number who string regex is used?? and how can validate this number using java script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143068/discussion-between-yashar-aliabasi-and-coderwill).

Comment: it seems control keys like BackSpace, Delete etc not working on it :|

Comment: tanx dear @YasharAliabbasi for excellent answer , simple and usefull :)

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to keep most of the code as it is, I would suggest checking that the name is not empty before validating and checking on the `keyup` event, after the character is available. Otherwise, the validation fails because the regex requires at least one character. Please note @yashar-aliabasi has a good answer because the validation will also run on pasting and the textbox triggering a change event as well as preventing invalid characters from entering the textbox.

```js
function text(name)
{
    var name = $(name).val();
    if (name.length > 0) {
     just_persian(name);
    }
}

 function just_persian(str) {
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
    if (!p.test(str)) {
        alert("not format");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtn" onkeyup="text(this)" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for the helping but now i want to also add Passport number validation and National Id validation for iran so any idea about it this??

Comment: Hello can you help me for that national id validation for iran?

Comment: I can try! Is the current regex `[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}` causing problems? What requirements is it not meeting? Do you have another question open for the id validation at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    document.getElementById('nameFa').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){

         if ((e.charCode >= 97 && e.charCode <= 122) || (e.charCode>=65 && e.charCode<=90)){
            alert("Language is english");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        else if(isPersian(e.key))
             alert("Language is Persian");
        else
             alert("Others");
    });

    function isPersian(str){
        var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
        return p.test(str);
    }
```

And

```
    <input type="text" id="nameFa">
```